# echo issues with datetime-local format

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I've tried numerous times to figure this out and I'm failing to update the code on an older page I've taken control of.

I've got some code (yes, I know I'm still working with mysql, but it's an old page and I haven't the time to rewrite everything for mysqli at the moment).

Code:

```
 <?php   
    mysql_connect("some hostname", "someusername", "somepassword") or   
 die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("somedatabase") or die(mysql_error()); 

    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';");//GET and POST
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';");//POST
    $order = "  SELECT *
                FROM tbl_patientdoseinformation
                WHERE patientdoseID = '$id'";

      $result = mysql_query($order);
      $datetimestated = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime($row['datetimestated']));

      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
```

and an form with input code of:

```
 <input type="datetime-local" name="stated" value="<?php echo $datetimestated; ?>">
```

However, when it echos out, it is most certainly not the date/time that is in the database.

The value of the record I"m working with should be
07/20/2016 10:00 AM

The value that echos is:
12/31/1969 06:00 PM

Comment: Please write the exact value of `$row['datetimestated']`

Comment: Maybe try to fetch the data, before you try to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to use `$row` before you retrieve it from the result set

```
<?php   
    mysql_connect("some hostname", "someusername", "somepassword") or   
 die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("somedatabase") or die(mysql_error()); 

    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8';");//GET and POST
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';");//POST
    $order = "  SELECT *
                FROM tbl_patientdoseinformation
                WHERE patientdoseID = '$id'";

      $result = mysql_query($order);

      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

      // move to after the fetch
      $datetimestated = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime($row['datetimestated']));

?>
```

Comment: thank you for that. I can't believe I was doing that. This was the fix. appreciate your help. have a great day!